# Why my vim have these char, how can I let them disappear?

Tags: vim

I am learning the VIM, I don't know what I type wrong, it shows me some strange char, how can I clear that??

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't typing wrong, vim is just [informing you](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_02.html#02.1) that there is no more text, or that some part of it does not fit to screen. You want to see these things.

The tildes `~` mean that those lines are after the end of the document; there is no more text. You cannot disable this indicator.

The at signs `@` mean that those lines are part of a paragraph that would extend past the end of the screen. To disable them and make vim show as much of the line as possible, you can [`:set display+=lastline`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'display'), but this might end up confusing later.